# Are there any JRE/JDK exploits that do not require the presence of applets or plugins?

Tags: web-browser, exploit, vulnerability, java, cve

For triggering a Java exploit should applets be enabled in the user's machine?

That is, in a drive by download scenario, can just visiting a malicious URL trigger an exploit/cve on the user's pc due to an outdated Java version, again without requiring applets?

Consider using a modern browser like Chrome which has the applets/plugins disabled.Is such an exploit still possible?

Is just having the applets disabled and running an outdated java version safe?

Comment: To be clear, do you mean vulnerabilities beyond having an application that uses Java that becomes exploitable by, say, a buffer overflow in a networking library? Does it install any entry points other than the binaries?

Comment: I mean in any agnostic way to somehow triger a JRE CVE without using applets,just because you use an outdated/unpatched Java version

Comment: because in every report I've seen,to trigger an exploit you must have applets and a vunerable browser enabled

Comment: So sure, if you have some program using Java, and it loads an image from an untrusted source and the JRE has a buffer overflow in handling that type of image, there you have it. Or perhaps it's XML and an XML inclusion vulnerability, or whatever.

Comment: To give some context,there is this legacy applet which runs only with a specific Firefox version,while the url's it can touch are restricted so that the user cannot access any malicious sites (supposedly) in order to trigger an applet/browser plugin exploit.

Comment: So I'm wondering in case the payload is delivered in other ways by say, a phishing email that redirects to a url which doesn't get loaded by the Firefox version that is allowed to run applets but by the default system (modern) browser,if it's safe or still at risk?

Comment: What do you think?